# File not loading from URL

Tags: file, url, load, mp4, jwplayer

Why am I not able to visit the .mp4 file which this player loads in on the actual website? I don't understand, since the file it's publicity is open (I can load it on the actual page, so why not here?)

```
   jwplayer("vplayer").setup({
        sources: [{file:"http://5.79.65.54/kj2vyibvei6vtaw52bjj424ffdpihhh3faz3hoh53hp7klpimhf6ti4evxla/v.mp4",label:"240p"},
{file:"http://5.79.65.54/kj2vyibvei6vtaw52bjj424ffdpihhh3faz3hoh53orpklpimhf6pwsffuyq/v.mp4",label:"360p"},
{file:"http://5.79.65.54/kj2vyibvei6vtaw52bjj424ffdpihhh3faz3hoh53vypklpimhf7yyyh44fq/v.mp4",label:"720p"}],
        image: "http://5.79.65.54/i/01/00000/43w5a2pzxepn.jpg",
        skin: "",
        duration:"6740",
        width: 728,
        height: 410,
        preload:"auto",
        primary:"flash",
        startparam: "start"
```

It's for the following line:

```
http://5.79.65.54/kj2vyibvei6vtaw52bjj424ffdpihhh3faz3hoh53vypklpimhf7yyyh44fq/v.mp4
```

It would help me a lot, if someone could explain me on why this is happening!

Comment: Are you seriously asking how to scrape someone else's content, without going through their own site?

Comment: It looks like the site only allows for certain IPs to access it, this would prevent downloading / leeching of their content.

Comment: @MisterNeutron They're allowed to be embedded, so it actually isn't stealing, right?

Comment: Who is they? What is the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says the ip is wrong so my best guess is that the ip address of the hosted site is in a whitelist.

**Update**

To expand on my answer:

Try to open the url directly to the mp4 file in the browser and open the console (Chrome = F12 etc..). You will see that the server returns **HTTP status code 403 Forbidden**

Status code 403 responses are the result of the web server being configured to deny access, for some reason, to the requested resource by the client.

Now, this is a bit of a trickery and you **MUST** make sure you're allowed to do this. Open the same URL in the browser: thevideos.tv/embed-pmmp2xh1slwm-728x410.html

now open up the developer console in the browser. Chrome = F12 etc..
Now right click on the table element and add AFTER it the following:

```
<video><source src="http://46.105.106.46/kj2vzb7wei6vtaw52bfz4nmggyev2pof5ka5cfja62xmnfzhv6ajzp4gbyoa/v.mp4"></video>
```

Click somewhere on the webpage with the flashplayer and watch the video gets embedded. Now try to right click the html5 video and click "Save video" (Make sure you are allowed to do this)

**What did we learn from this?**

The video is requestet from that particular web site. We tricked the web server holding the resource to accept the request since it came from thevideos.tv.

Thats it. Click [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) to learn more about HTTP status codes, click [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.4) to learn more about the 403 status code.

Comment: What do you mean, by saying that the IP address is wrong? I can visit the image (http://5.79.65.54/i/01/00000/43w5a2pzxepn.jpg) on the same ip address without any trouble.

Comment: Here i get the message that i am forbidden to access the image.


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WHbbB.png

Comment: I'm not sure why you're receiving that message, but i'm able to visit the file just fine. The only problem i'm currently having is that whenever I visit the .mp4 file, it's not loading. I can see a player, but the actual file isn't loading. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I get the forbidden message as well, but if I go to the address again and press enter, for example, it shows up. However, its very clear to me that this site is trying to save bandwidth and protect themselves from people trying to steal their content, so you aren't going to get much help on here for that...

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer They're allowing their files to be embedded, the only problem they have (well a problem I see) is that the player isn't configured properly. So what I actually wanted to do, was, loading in the file (which they allow to be embedded) and configure the player myself (to be more user friendly for my visitors).

Comment: Who is they? Do you have an example of one of their embeds? From the looks of it, it looks like their files can't be accessed from certain IPs...

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer I'm sorry for the late response. But here is an example: http://thevideos.tv/embed-pmmp2xh1slwm-728x410.html in order to view the website, you have to manually put in the url in your browser.

Comment: "Video embed restricted for this domain" when trying to use the provided link

Comment: @Dan-LeviTømta As I mentioned, you have to manual put the link inside of your URL bar

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, so basically there is no way in order to embed it myself then requesting the file from thevideos's IP address?

Comment: Sure, there are lots of ways doing this, but that you have to ask in another question since it is out of the scope of this question. It basically depends on what kind of tech you're using. If you find my answer most helpful, please tick it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Dan-LeviTømta Done that, would you like to start a chat with me, since I am terrible at asking questions, and you're basically the only one understanding what I want / need :P

Comment: I cant help you with that, it goes hand in hand with hacking the target web server. I suggest you find another way to approach this challenge instead of diving into a whole lot of new things you must learn to achieve what you want. The easiest way is probably just this: Contact the owner of the website that is hosting these mp4's and ask how you can embed their video files.

Comment: I agree with this. I can't even get to this link. I get "Video embed restricted for this domain" as well.